# Debugging an external ignite node from IDE

Tags: ignite

I can start multiple nodes from within the IDE and the breakpoints work. But, there are some aspects that are different when the node has been started externally (using the startup scripts). I want to debug the jobs running on that node from within the IDE. How do i do that? I am guessing it is similar to remote server debugging, but not sure how to do that in Ignite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the following with IntelliJ IDEA:

1. Specify JVM options when starting an external node:

`-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005`

2. Add a remote debugging configuration with default settings (which correspond to the above)
3. Start a remote node and attach a debugger

Comment: After you pointed out, I found this option was also in the comments of the startup script. Uncommenting one line, and using a run config on Idea, the debugging went smoothly.